# Create symbol and attach image from library to symbol with code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I assigned a class of bgMountain to an image in my library. How do I (programmatically) create a new symbol, and attach that image to the newly created symbol?

Comment: That's my question :) . I know how to do what I just said via the IDE... but was wondering if there's a way to do it strictly with AS3 code and what classes/methods I'd use for it.

Comment: Have I answered your question so far? :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Embed(source="path_to_hero.png")] //or .jpeg
public class Hero extends Bitmap {
  public function Hero(){

  }
}

public class Main extends Sprite(){
  public function Main():void {
    var hero:Hero = new Hero() ;
    hero.x = 50 ;
    hero.y = 50 ;
    stage.addChild(hero) ;
  }
}
```

Here is the [tutorial](http://blog.framethrower.de/content/how-embed-assets-fonts-images-or-sounds-compile-time-your-as3-swf)

Also, [using SWF library](http://summitprojectsflashblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/11/creating-instances-of-library-items-from-loaded-swfs/)

Comment: ah so this is a more direct method as opposed to loading the image into the library and accessing from there?

Comment: +1 Sorry for waiting a day to select this as an answer :D . Was messing with it for my use as I'm using external classes... still wrapping my head around OOP as well so I'm like a deaf man walking through a hallway with a blindfold on =/

Comment: It's fine, you will get used to OOP gradually and will like it sooo much after that :)